# Why does the SELinux filesystem have it's own null device?

Tags: devices, selinux

Looking through `/sys/fs/selinux`, I found this:

```
# ls -l /sys/fs/selinux/null
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 1, 3 Jan 24 02:47 /sys/fs/selinux/null
```

Which is identical to `/dev/null`:

```
# ls -l /dev/null
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 1, 3 Jan 24 10:47 /dev/null
```

So what's the point of SELinux having its own null device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is scarcely explained in [Implementing SELinux as a Linux Security Module](http://www.nsa.gov/research/_files/selinux/papers/module/x302.shtml)

> This results in a populated selinuxfs filesystem and sets up the special null
>   device node used by SELinux when it closes unauthorized files upon a
>   context-changing execve.

Apparently programs cannot use `/dev/null` directly while in SELinux-context and they [needed](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/akpm/patches/2.6/2.6.8.1/2.6.8.1-mm1/broken-out/selinux-add-null-device-node-to-selinuxfs-remove-open_devnull.patch) their own version. This was formerly known as [open_devnull](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=108664922032035) and its [inception](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/201656) gives a few more details on why this was needed:

> This patch against 2.6.6-rc3 changes the SELinux module to try to reset
>   any descriptors it closes on exec (due to a lack of permission by the
>   new domain to the inherited open file) to refer to the null device. 
>   This counters the problem of SELinux inducing program misbehavior,
>   particularly due to having descriptors 0-2 closed when the new domain is
>   not allowed access to the caller's tty.  This is primarily to address
>   the case where the caller is trusted with respect to the new domain, as
>   the untrusted caller case is already handled via AT_SECURE and glibc
>   secure mode.

Comment: Sound like technocratic gibberish to me, but still is an answer.